# target pools vs backend services vs regional backend service difference?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

While exploring google cloud platform's Load balancer options
*Advanced Menu* shows multiple options which are a bit confusing.

there are multiple backends

- backend service -> HTTP(S) LB
- backend bucket  -> HTTP(S) LB
- regional backend service -> internal LB
- target pools  -> TCP LB

Just going through documentations for [target pools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/target-pools) and [backend-service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service) Looks to me they have similar parameters to configure and in the *basic menu* both are listed as backends.

I understand that **target pools** are used by TCP forwarding rules where as **backend-service** used by url map ( http/s Load balancer).

But Are there any other difference between these or is it just names?

Answer (score 9):

A [Backend Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-bucket) allow you to use [Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets) with HTTP(S) load balancing. It can handle request for static content. This option would be useful for a webpage that with static content and it would avoid the costs of resources than a instance would need.

The [Backend Service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service) is a centralized service that manages backends, which in turn manage an indeterminate number of instances that handle user requests.

The [Target Pools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/target-pools) resource defines a group of instances that should receive incoming traffic from forwarding rules. When a forwarding rule directs traffic to a target pool, Google Compute Engine picks an instance from these target pools based on a hash of the source IP and port and the destination IP and port.

This is why they both are listed as backend-services, because at the end they both do the same, but they specify for two different kind of load balancer. The backend service works for HTTP(S) load balancer and target pools are used for [forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules).

Comment: So what is difference between Backend Service that manage instances and Target Pools which also manages  instances , both seems to manage backends!  I know one is for TCP forwarding another for HTTPS , keen to understand if there are any other differences

Comment: The target pools redirect directly to the instances, while the Backend Service manage a group of backends, each of those have a number of instances under their control (This instances can also be shared between different backends). The Backend Service can also accomplish other kind of requirements (as can be some host or path rules) to decide which backend to choose.

Answer (score 5):

"*A Network load balancer* (unlike HTTP(s) load balancer) *is a pass-through load balancer. It does not proxy connections from clients.*" On same note, TargetPools use forwarding rules, backend services use target proxies. Request is sent to instance in target pool "*based on a hash of the source IP and port, destination IP and port, and protocol*". Backend service has different mechanism to choose an instance group for e.g URL maps.